# what's the relationship between GtkTextIter and GtkTextMark?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gnome

The Devhelp says that GtkTextIter will be invalidated when the contents in GtkBuffer are changed and the GtkTextMark solve this problem. So how to insert GtkTextMark into buffer? and how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a mark with [`gtk_text_buffer_create_mark()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-create-mark). Usually you will want to give the mark a name so that you can retrieve it later, or move it.

Then, when you need to re-validate your iterator, use [`gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-get-iter-at-mark).